# How to set table column width of itextSharp pdf table/document

Tags: c#-4.0, itext, pdfptable

```
    Document document;
    document.NewPage();

     System.Collections.ArrayList columnWidth = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < 2)
            {
                columnWidth.Add(2f);
            }
            else
            {
                columnWidth.Add(1f);
            }
        }       

    float[] headerWidths = columnWidth.OfType<float>().Select(w => (float)w).ToArray();

    PdfPTable tableHeader = new PdfPTable(3);
    tableHeader.AddCell(GetCell(Col1Name));
    tableHeader.AddCell(GetCell(Col2Name));
    tableHeader.AddCell(GetCell(DescriptionColumnName));

    tableHeader.SetWidths(headerWidths);
    tableHeader.HeaderRows = 1;

    PopulatePDFCell(tableHeader);
    document.Add(tableHeader);
```

How can i set varying column widths for each column individually? The DescriptionColumnName width is expected to be much wider and Col1Name is not expected to be equal to Col2Name in width?

Comment: Can you give us more detail on what you're trying to do? The above appears logical as far as I can tell. Also, it seems that you know this but just to be clear, widths in a `PdfPTable` are relative so `1,2,1` is the same as `2,4,2`.